# Graph coloring problem with violations

Tags: graphs, optimization, colorings

I would like a name for the following problem. We consider a relaxed vertex coloring problem, where

- Let $k$ be the number of colors
- Let $B$ be the set of edges violating coloring, i.e., $$B := \{(u,v) \in E \mid c(u) = c(v)\}$$
- Then the objective is something like $k + \beta |B| \to \min$ over all colorings (for some $\beta$).

Does this problem have a name?

Somehow, I can't find anything. "Approximate graph coloring" and similar queries talk about approximations for graph coloring.
Maybe there is another objective of form $k^\alpha + \beta |B|^\gamma$ (and maybe coefficients may depend on $|V|$)?

I am particularly interested in the hardness of such problems (the harder the better). E.g., hardness for coloring is [pretty crazy](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.5216). I am also particularly interested in a weighted version of this problem, e.g.,  $k + \beta \sum_{e \in B} w_e \to \min$.

Comment: Dmitry, are you acquainted with (physical) [frustration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrical_frustration)?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, I'm not familiar (I'm also almost zero in physics). I took a brief look at the article, didn't really understand it. Did I understand correctly that they only consider k=2? I need arbitrary $k$.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, the closest problem I can think of is [Correlation clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_clustering), but there is no dependence on $k$ in the objective function.

Comment: @Dmitry You may be able to find something interesting for the case $k=2$ in Mézard & Montanari's [Information, Physics, and Computation](https://web.stanford.edu/~montanar/RESEARCH/book.html)

Comment: @Dmitry Also, for an introduction, you may want to read Brian Hayes's [On the Threshold](http://bit-player.org/wp-content/extras/bph-publications/AmSci-2003-01-Hayes-survey-propagation.pdf) (2003) [PDF].

Comment: If you want to maximize the number of properly colored edges, that's know as maximum cut. That's usually with two colors, but you can generalize.